# The caller does not have permission to execute the request

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm using this API to try for business and have the happen with API, at the moment I'm also owner admin and have full permission with my account to intergrate with BIM360 API.

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/index/v2/projects/b419675a-f787-465a-b701-ef89f72b1a59/indexes/1
```

It respone for me with information like this :

```
{
    "detail": "User is not authorized to access this resource with an explicit deny",
    "title": "The caller does not have permission to execute the request.",
    "type": "Unauthorized"
}
```

Can I know the reason with that ? any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem resolved by change to 3-legged OAuth v2

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error too. In my case it was because I'd mistakenly used an authentication token retrieved via a 2-legged flow for an API call that required a 3-legged token. (`Authentication Context: user context required`)